# Paragraph tag closes after blur event

Tags: jquery, html, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor, froala

I'm using Froala editor in Web view inside a desktop application. I have a list of custom tags that I need to append to Froala's text when the user presses the button outside of the editor. For that, I'm calling

```
$('#froala_editor').froalaEditor('html.insert', 'my text', false);
```

The problem is: When the editor is losing the `focus(blur)` (after or before), it's closing the `<p>` tag, so whatever I insert after, goes to the new line. Is there a way to prevent Froala from clong the `<p>` tag on `blur()` event?

*P.S I don't want to use custom toolbar buttons.* 
Thanks in advance.

**Screenshot of the app:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a solution we used at.js integration in Froala. At.js giving you flexibility to insert custom elements inside the editor using @(or any character specified in config).